# Mongo db database not accessible from shell, data storage

Tags: mongodb, deployd, database

I am working with deployd which uses mongoDB as a db on Ubuntu OS.

All databases of mongoDB are accessible from within mongodb shell but my question is when I create a new project with deployd I can store/read/modify records but this new database is not accessible from mongodb shell, how do i do that?.

Database files for this new project are stored within the application directory not in mongoDB default data directory.

Also what's the difference of mongoDB as a database within application and MongoDB as a global database for all applications.

Currently all collections are accessible using `dpd` object like

```
dpd.albums.get(inputParams, function(resultSet, err){ //handle result});
```

While I would like to access these collections using something like

```
db.albums.find(); //within mongod shell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there are a few misconceptions here about the deploying with "deployd".

Firstly "deployd" depends on an existing mongoDB installation on it's deployed host or is otherwise configured to use a host on another server. So where "data files" are kept are generally a point of condifuration. All that "deployd" tries to do is start the "mongod" instance as it's own instance is started should the configuration be local.

No matter what you do, all of the options are available in configuration. There is a good sample in the documentation [here](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/run-script.html):

```js
var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  env: 'staging',
  db: {
    host: 'my.production.mongo.host',
    port: 27105,
    name: 'my-db',
    credentials: {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see the host and port settings are specified in the configuration of the application itself, so where you are not using the default "mongoDB" host and port then add them to the command line options, as in:

```js
mongo --host my.production.mongo.host --port 27105
```

So even on the same localhost, note that the instance does not use the default `27017` port but a different one that you would need to specify when connecting.

Also see the [mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/) command documentation as well as the [deployd](http://docs.deployd.com/) documentation.

Comment: Yes, after some study now I know this but the problem is when start deployd using nohup, it fails to start its mongoDB instance and thats why I wanted to migrate all my data to mongoDB path where mongoDB as a service would start. Any idea how to start deployd with nohup? or any suggestion how to avoid this situation? I'm stuck here